# State Model Viewer

Tags: smallworld-gis

Is anyone aware of a way to change the change the state of a design to a previous state in GE Small World. I'm working in version 4.2. The Design is in Data Maintenance Updates, there doesn't seem to be a way to move the design to a previous state.